# Serial communication, confusion about buffer processing

Tags: c++, arduino, buffer

i am currently trying to work my way into using an arduino for some basic acceleration data output. The problem i am facing at the moment is my lack of basic understanding of how one is processing the data which is getting send through the serial port.
Firstly here is my simple arduino program:

```
void loop() {
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

  if (currentMillis - previousMillis > interval) {
    previousMillis = currentMillis;
    sendData();
  }

}

void sendData() {
      // read raw accel/gyro measurements from device
    accelgyro.getMotion6(&ax, &ay, &az, &gx, &gy, &gz);

    writeBuffer[0] = '<';
    writeBuffer[1] = lowByte(ax);
    writeBuffer[2] = highByte(ax);
    writeBuffer[3] = lowByte(ay);
    writeBuffer[4] = highByte(ay);
    writeBuffer[5] = lowByte(az);
    writeBuffer[6] = highByte(az);
    writeBuffer[7] = '>';

    Serial.write(writeBuffer, 8);         
    //Serial.write((uint8_t)(gx >> 8)); Serial.write((uint8_t)(gx & 0xFF));
    //Serial.write((uint8_t)(gy >> 8)); Serial.write((uint8_t)(gy & 0xFF));
    //Serial.write((uint8_t)(gz >> 8)); Serial.write((uint8_t)(gz & 0xFF));

    // blink LED to indicate activity
    blinkState = !blinkState;
    digitalWrite(LED_PIN, blinkState);
}
```

And here is my c++ code:

```
Serial* SP = new Serial("COM5");    // adjust as needed

    if (SP->IsConnected())
        printf("We're connected!\n");

    char incomingData[8] = "";          // don't forget to pre-allocate memory
    //printf("%s\n",incomingData);
    int dataLength = 8;
    int readResult = 0;

    while (SP->IsConnected())
    {
        readResult = SP->ReadData(incomingData, dataLength);
        //printf("Bytes read: (-1 means no data available) %i\n", readResult);

        if (readResult < 8 || incomingData[0] != '<' || incomingData[7] != '>') {
            continue;
        }

        char low = incomingData[1];
        char high = incomingData[2];

        int ax = (high << 8 | low);

        low = incomingData[3];
        high = incomingData[4];

        int ay = (high << 8 | low);

        low = incomingData[5];
        high = incomingData[6];

        int az = (high << 8 | low);

        printf("ax: %i, ay: %i, az: %i\n", ax, ay, az); 

        //Sleep(500);
    }
    return 0;
```

And this is how the read function works:

```
int Serial::ReadData(char *buffer, unsigned int nbChar)
{
    //Number of bytes we'll have read
    DWORD bytesRead;
    //Number of bytes we'll really ask to read
    unsigned int toRead;

    //Use the ClearCommError function to get status info on the Serial port
    ClearCommError(this->hSerial, &this->errors, &this->status);

    //Check if there is something to read
    if (this->status.cbInQue > 0)
    {
        //If there is we check if there is enough data to read the required number
        //of characters, if not we'll read only the available characters to prevent
        //locking of the application.
        if (this->status.cbInQue > nbChar)
        {
            toRead = nbChar;
        }
        else
        {
            toRead = this->status.cbInQue;
        }

        //Try to read the require number of chars, and return the number of read bytes on success
        if (ReadFile(this->hSerial, buffer, toRead, &bytesRead, NULL) && bytesRead != 0)
        {
            return bytesRead;
        }

    }

    //If nothing has been read, or that an error was detected return -1
    return -1;

}
```

Now as you can see i am marking my serial output with two markers "<" and ">". The problem on the client side is that i am not sure how to make sure that i really only read those blocks. How do i know if a complete block arrived? Do i have to read all the data into a buffer first and then process it? If i do that, how do i handle incomplete blocks (created from reading before a whole block was sent)? I am quite confused of how this concept works. Maybe someone can explain how this usally is tackled?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is just a bug in your SP->ReadData() call.  You want to start reading at dataLength and never read more than 8 bytes total.  So it should be SP->ReadData(&incomingData[dataLength], 8 - dataLength).  You can further improve it by throwing everything away until you get a `<`.

Answer (score 0):

With respect to reading data from regular serial ports, over normal serial cables, the most important thing to understand is that serial ports CAN have missing or corrupt data.

In your case it may be VERY unlikely, bordering on impossible - you are probably at a low baud rate, transmitting infrequently, short cables, etc, etc. But in the general case it starts to become likely at some point that you'll get corrupt data.

So, the way I'd try to read that packet is a small state machine that just drops corrupt packets on the floor:

- Drop characters till you receive a '<'
- Receive up to 6 characters into the buffer.
- If the next character is >, then process the message.
- Reset your buffer pointers and begin again.